# Overstay UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk, applications, overstaying

I am looking to apply for a UK YMS visa. I previously held a UK study visa in which I overstayed for 8 days but left voluntarily. Since my overstay I have also returned to the UK for a short period on a visitor visa in which I had no problems at the border. Is it likely that my current visa application will be rejected due to my overstay previously?

Comment: I note Gayot's [earlier *dicta*](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/73574/12065) to the effect that *once a non-visa national successfully applies for entry clearance, it basically wipes the record clean and gives the person a "fresh slate"*.  Given that you've had an entry clearance since the whole overstay issue, then on the basis of Gayot's words it seems likely to me that your chances are good.

Comment: Questions about work visas and long term residence should be asked on our sister site, [expatriates.se].

Comment: Sorry, I am a non-visa national and thus my subsequent visit has not been after applying for a visitor visa, I simply was able to enter via their automatic eGate system. Would this still count as an entry clearance?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have been since your overstay on a visitor visa does help the case, you will need to show the immigration officer that you will return to your home country.

A return ticket before the expiration of your visa will help your case, then the officer will see you are planning to leave the country on that date. Also sufficient proof-of-ties to your home country will help (family, work, etc.). But ultimately, it is up to the immigration officer and no-one can give a definite answer here.

Comment: Given that the YMS (Tier5) visa allows the holder to live, work, study etc in the UK for up to 2 years, I doubt a return ticket is practical https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-youth-mobility/eligibility General grounds for entry clearance refusal apply https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/791892/Tier_5_YMS_v13.0ext.pdf#page9